# Edit HTML in JavaScript variable using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, jquery-selectors

I have this code:

```
var a = '<span class="select-me">hohoho</span><input type="text" class="alias" />';
$(a).filter('input.alias').val('my new alias');
console.log(a);
```

Can I do this using jQuery `filter` method?

Am expect console.log(a),

```
<span class="select-me">hohoho</span><input type="text" class="alias" value="my new alias" />
```

Comment: Yes you can, but you need to close the quotes on type="text"

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? : ))

Comment: Not sure about what exactly your query is , still go through this [http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-data-attr-vs-class/12] . Hope it helps to make things clear.

Comment: @Anton actually it not right, the "a" object is not a valid selector

Comment: but when i console.log(a); it not change at all. it says '<span class="select-me">hohoho</span><input type="text class="alias" />'. i expect it should be '<span class="select-me">hohoho</span><input type="text class="alias" value="my new alias" />'

Comment: @kucingbelang4 .val() changes the property of the input not the attribute. If you want to change the attribute you must use .attr('value','new alias')

Comment: @Hiyasat the variable a is a valid selector when you wrap it with jQuery, it's like creating a new element $('<a>test</a>').appendTo('body')

Comment: @Anton idk but, it doesnt work, my value input not change at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the variable after you've changed it, also not that .val() will change the property of the input not the attribute. if you wish to change the attribute use `.attr('value','my new alias');`

```
var a = '<span class="select-me">hohoho</span><input type="text" class="alias" />';
a = $(a).filter('input.alias').val('my new alias');
console.log(a);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9evdq/)

Comment: i see, but i dont want return to window that early , because i want it return to back-end of js, but thanks for ur explanation